# Deadlock when dropping multiple constraints on multiple tables at the same time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, deadlock, constraint

**Background**

We have a data warehouse process that calls the following code:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC maintenance.sp_fk_statements @P1,@P2,@P3',
    N'@P1 varchar(3),
    @P2 varchar(9),
    @P3 varchar(4)',
    'dbo',
    'table_name',
    'DROP'
```

This sp pulls a list of drop constraint statements from another table, loads it into a cursor, and then iterates through the cursor calling `exec(@sql)` on the drop statement.

An example of what one of the drop statements looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_constraint_name];
```

---

**The Problem**

The stored procedure above is called on several tables at once.  This didn't cause issues before, but starting last night has started causing deadlocks.

Specifically, the deadlock is occuring on the object *mssqlsystemresource.sys.fn_MSconstraint_columns*, with this query (captured by SentryOne):

```
insert into @columns
--
-- PK,UQ are key constraints
-- (excludes implicity added "uniqifier" columns)
select  schema_name(sys.key_constraints.schema_id) as schema_name,
        sys.key_constraints.name   as constraint_name,
        sys.key_constraints.type,
        sys.columns.name as constraint_column_name,
        sys.columns.column_id as constraint_column_id
from    sys.key_constraints WITH ( READPAST )
join    sys.indexes
on      sys.key_constraints.parent_object_id = sys.indexes.object_id
    and sys.key_constraints.unique_index_id = sys.indexes.index_id
join    sys.index_columns
on      sys.indexes.index_id = sys.index_columns.index_id
    and sys.indexes.object_id = sys.index_columns.object_id
join    sys.columns
on      sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.columns.object_id
    and sys.index_columns.column_id = sys.columns.column_id
where   sys.key_constraints.type in ('PK','UQ')
    and sys.key_constraints.parent_object_id = @objid

union

--fake PK rows for indexed view
select
```

I am unsure as to why this would be causing deadlocks on this particular resource all of a sudden, when this process has been running fine for a while.  Is there anything I can do to fix this other than tell them to drop the table constraints in series rather than parallel?

---

**Note**: Yes, that SQL query is incomplete, that's how it's shown in SentryOne.

Comment: Do a recompile on the stored proc. Maybe it has a "bad" plan now.

Comment: @TaraKizer I'll try that and see what happens

Comment: @TaraKizer nope, same thing happened